# How to set the source of paper for a printer?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I want choose a custom source of paper when printing.
I wrote this code:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = domainUpDown1.SelectedItem.ToString();

int i = 1;

foreach (int x in consent)
{
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
    pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = Convert.ToInt16(x);
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = PaperSourceKind.Upper;
   // MessageBox.Show(pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource.ToString());
    if (x != 0)
    {
        pd.Print();
    }
    i++;
}
```

but

```
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = PaperSourceKind.Upper;
```

causes this error:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSourceKind' to
> 'System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSource'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is because you are trying to assign `PaperSourceKind.Upper` (which is an enum of type `PaperSourceKind`) to `pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource` (which is a class of type `PaperSource`).

Instead, try

```cs
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = new PaperSource() { RawKind = (int)PaperSourceKind.Upper };
```

Comment: thanks :D 
can i use number 1 instead PaperSourceKind.Upper ?
@Ekas

Comment: Yes, you can use `{ RawKind = 1 }`, though it might not be a great practice.